# JQuery: Getting .index() of elements added with .append()

Tags: jquery, indexing, append

JQuery v1.7.2

I'm adding elements to the screen after the user makes a selection from a dropdown. I'm doing this w/ .append():

```
var html = '<li><input type="hidden" name="hidden_' + ID + '" id="hidden_' + ID + '" value="' + ID + '"/><p>' + Name + '<a href="#" onClick="remove($(this));">Close</a></p></li>'
$('#sortable').append(html);
```

When the form is submitted I need to go through each of the hidden fields and get their value and current order (the user can move them up and down the page). I'm trying to do this w/ .index():

```
$('#sortable input:hidden[id*="hidden_"]').each(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
    alert($(this).index());
});
```

When I run this code, the value is coming through fine, but the index is always 0. I tried wrapping it all in

```
$(function () {
    $("#create").on("submit", function (event) {
    });
});
```

but that didn't work either.

Is there something I'm doing wrong, or is this happening because I appended the elements?

Comment: Have you tried using [`.each(function(index) { });`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) instead

Comment: Wow, now I feel silly. Thanks Danny.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first parameter of `each` function is the *index* of current loop.

> .each( function(index, Element) )

```
$('#sortable input:hidden[id^="hidden_"]').each(function(index){
    alert(this.value);
    alert(index);
});
```

Comment: Oh, of course! .each is a loop so of course there's an index. Thanks @undefined. I do have one question - why did you change the selector from *= to ^=?

Comment: @shimmoril You are welcome, I have used `attribute starts with` selector, it doesn't change the selected elements in this case. You had used `attribute contains selector` I though that it wasn't necessary here.